# AngularJS directive require parent directive doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, require, directive

I want to make a categories tree with checkboxs (which is a recusive list) directive.

I did a directive called ***categoriesTreeContainer*** that containes all the list of categories

and I did another directive called ***categoryItem*** that containes the category item which is the child of ***categoriesTreeContainer***

this is what I did ***categoriesTreeContainer***:

```
myApp.directive('categoriesTreeContainer', function(){
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    template : '<category-item ng-repeat="category in categoriesTree" category="category"></category-item>',
    scope    : {
        categoriesTree : "=categoriestree",
        selectedCategories : "=ngModel",
    },

    controller : function($scope, $element, $attrs){
        $scope.selectedCategories = [];

        $scope.onSelectionChange = function(category){
            console.log('yah');
        }
    }
}
```

})

for the ***categoryItem***:

```
myApp.directive('categoryItem', function($compile){
return {
    require: '^categoriesTreeContainer',
    restrict : 'E',
    //replace  : true,
    transclude : true,
    scope    : {
        category : "=category"
    },
    link     : function(scope, element, attrs, categoriesTreeCtrl){
        console.log(categoriesTreeCtrl);

        if(scope.category.subCategories.length>0){

            element.append($compile(
                '<div class="panel panel-default panel-treelist">'+
                '<div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title">'+
                '<label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{category.$$hashKey}}">'+
                '<input type="checkbox" ng-change="categoriesTreeCtrl.onSelectionChange(category)"  ng-model="category.selected" />'+
                ' {{category.name}}</label></h4></div><div id="{{category.$$hashKey}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">'+
                '<div class="panel-body">'+
                '<category-item id="{{category.$$hashKey}}" ng-repeat="subCategory in category.subCategories" category="subCategory" categoriestree="categoriesTree" ng-model="selectedCategories">'+
                '</category-item></div></div></div>'
                )(scope))
        }else{
            element.append($compile('<label><input ng-change="categoriesTreeCtrl.onSelectionChange(category)" type="checkbox" ng-model="category.selected"> {{category.name}}</label><br/>')(scope));
        }
    }
}
```

})

and in the DOM:

```
<categories-tree-container categoriestree="categoriesTree" ng-model="selectedCategories"></categories-tree-container>
```

The tree is rendered as I wanted.
The problem is that the **required** controller '^categoriesTreeContainer' in the categoryItem directive is void.  I did a `console.log(categoriesTreeCtrl)` for the `categoriesTreeCtrl` in the **link** function and this what is what I get:

`c {}`, A void object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It will easier to try if you make some jsfiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `categoriesTreeCtrl` will be `void object` because the controller has nothing. If you need to access `categoriesTreeCtrl.onSelectionChange` from child directive, you should not put the `onSelectionChange` as part of it's `$scope`, but define it as the controller's property.

```
controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
      this.onSelectionChange = function(category){ ... };
 // $scope.onSelectionChange = function(category){...}
}
```

**Additional :**
the `categoriesTreeCtrl` on the child directive is not equal to `$scope.categoriesTreeCtrl`, which means, you can't call `categoriesTreeCtrl` from you template. Look at the `ng-change` value.

Comment: @Sn0opr, accept it than! that way other people will benefit from it by knowing it solves the issue at hand.

Comment: I did it, before, but I think it was a bug, done one more time :)